# What's the grammar of "You kiss me tomorrow, I'll bite you face off!"?

Tags: ellipsis, subjunctives

"Zootopia" around 00:23:37/01:48:32

There is a YouTube [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hT_wx7qJCmA) (by the way, is "clip" an appropriate word?):

> Nick Wilde: *Hey, no kiss bye-bye for daddy?*
>   Finnick: *You kiss me tomorrow, I'll bite your face off!*

*Question:* Is "You kiss me tomorrow" subjunctive?
Does it mean "*If* you kiss me tomorrow"? Then why is "if" missing?
And what does "I'll" stand for? Is it "I would"?

Comment: *clip* usage is OK. But add the relevant dialog (the phrase in question and any necessary context) to your question. Over time links change or go away, so they are OK for reference but not your main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The future simple "will" (I'll = I will) is used in English for making promises and threats.

> I will sue you (threat)
>   I'll be careful (promise)

Finnick, the fennec fox, is threatening to hurt Nick Wilde, if the red fox kisses him the next day.

The subordinate clause in the Zootopia exchange is “You kiss me tomorrow”, by removing the "if" in the *[protasis](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/protasis)*, the speaker is *warning* Finnick that his face will be bitten off is a ***certainty*** not a  probability.

> **I"ll bite** your face **off**

*I'll bite your face off* is the main clause, it is the CONSEQUENCE based on the condition that Nick kisses Finnick.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is how the character talks. It sounds rough, which is part of the joke.

The little Fennec fox looks cute and pretends to be a baby, but now we find that he is actually an adult, and one who talks like a mobster.

It does mean "if", but it isn't a subjunctive, it is just two sentences in the simple present and the "will" future, used to express basic facts, and so emphasise the certainty of the conclusion. But don't talk this way, unless you want to sound like a gangster.

> You talk that way; you'll sound like a wiseguy. Capisce?