# How to understand the "good" in "She hustled you good!"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Zootopia" around 00:36:35/01:48:32

> **Nick**: *[through carrot pen]*{by the way, why not "through THE carrot pen"?} "200 bucks a day, Fluff. 365 days a year, since I was *12*."
>
> **Judy**: Actually, it's your word against yours. And if you want this pen, you're going to help me find this poor missing otter, or the only place you'll be selling pawpsicles is the prison cafeteria. *[grins]* It's called a hustle, sweetheart.
>
> *[Slight pause]*
>
> **Finnick**: She hustled you. *[opens the stroller, laughing]* She hustled you ***good***! You're a cop now, Nick! You're gonna need one of these. *[slaps his police sticker on Nick's shirt. Nick frowns]* Have fun working with the fuzz! *[leaves still laughing]*

(https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Zootopia)

A clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZdV-BZUYOQ

---

relatives: [What's the grammar of "You kiss me tomorrow, I'll bite you face off!"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/168836/whats-the-grammar-of-you-kiss-me-tomorrow-ill-bite-you-face-off/)

Comment: To corroborate the answers below, [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English Online](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/good) says "You will sometimes hear people say 'The team played good', especially in American English, but this is a non-standard use." and defines *good* as an adverb (as well as an adjective, etc.) that means "well. Many teachers think this is not correct English", labelling it as "informal, spoken, especially American English".

Answer (score 2):

It is colloquial speech that means "She cheated you and was very clever in how she did so or she took quite a lot of money from you when she cheated you."

> She cheated you *well*.

would be the "correct" grammar.

Compare

> I like movies where things *blow up real good*.

In other words, I like movies *with lots of big explosions*.

This is non-standard colloquial speech.

Answer (score 1):

to do something good as in:
- to get you good
- to cheat you good
- to hustle you good

Good there means **really**. It often is used for well (He did it good.), but often also means really, an intensifying adverb. In another words, to accomplish something completely.

- to really got you.
- to really cheat someone
- to really hustle someone

This use of good is very common in American colloquial speech and is marked as uneducated. However, people often will use it even when educated but they use it knowingly. The same is true of ain't, for example.